# OSError: Tesseract not found in environment. Check variables and PATH

Tags: python, python-import, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use img2table to read the data in scanned images. I'm starting with a basic example and I keep getting an OSError: Tesseract not found in environment. Check variables and PATH.

Here's my code:

```
from img2table.document import Image
from img2table.ocr import TesseractOCR

img = Image("mark sheet.jpg")
tesseract = TesseractOCR()

# Extract tables with Tesseract and PaddleOCR
tables = img.extract_tables(ocr=tesseract, borderless_tables=True)

tables[0].df
```

Here's the error:
File

```
"C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\img2table\ocr\tesseract.py", line 56, in __init__
    raise EnvironmentError("Tesseract not found in environment. Check variables and PATH")
```

It seems like the library I installed isn't finding something in some environment.
I have no idea how to proceed.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because Python cannot find the Tesseract executable in your runtime path. Tesseract is an external OCR library, outside of the `pytesseract` python library. `pytesseract` simply acts as a wrapper to interact with the Tesseract library. So in addition to installing pytesseract with `pip`, you need to download the Tesseract OCR executable and add it to your `PATH` so Python can find it.

This guide seems to outline the whole process pretty well: https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/blog/ocr-tools/tesseract-ocr-windows/

Here are the official installation docs: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html